# Java importing animations as obj files

Tags: java

I was wondering if my idea of adding animation is a reasonable way to do it or if this would cause major issues..

When I have an animation made in blender I can export every frame of the animation as a separate obj file. In my engine I would then tell the program to loop through all the obj files to recreate the animation.

So it would start with the first obj file, display it for about 0.2 seconds, then replace it with the next obj file and the next and then the next and so on until it reaches the last one, then it repeats the whole process.

Is this a smart way to go about it or absolutely not?

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Have a look at http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-spritesheet-animation--gamedev-13099

Comment: Yea, I know how sprite sheets work.. my question was rather 3d-ish you now, like with the obj files I mentinned.. I was just wondering if my idea might cause performance issues (looping through numerous obj files in order to get an animation..) but thanks anyway, might need that reference for another project..